# SQL Server - error when creating stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT count(*) as Colcunt 
FROM tbl_Calibration_Transaction
WHERE CardId = @CardId 
  AND ScalingMachine= @ScalingMachine 

IF (Colcunt = 0 )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_Calibration_Transaction
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: please ask yourself, if you get just the info you provided here, could you recreate the problem from scratch? is it really really all we need to know? is it presented in a nice, easy to understand way? should you really use a variable with "cunt" in it (or do you mean count, maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Colcunt int;
Select @Colcunt  = count(*) 
from tbl_Calibration_Transaction 
where CardId = @CardId and ScalingMachine= @ScalingMachine 

IF (@Colcunt = 0 ) BEGIN INSERT INTO tbl_Calibration_Transaction ...
```

Comment: Still THE SAME error? Even when there is NO Colcunt at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Colcunt INT

SET @Colcunt=(SELECT count(*)
FROM tbl_Calibration_Transaction
WHERE CardId = @CardId AND ScalingMachine= @ScalingMachine )

    IF (@Colcunt = 0 )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_Calibration_Transaction
```